# Подскажите код WordPress, выводящий сообщение, если пытаются отправить коментарий с html тегом "href=" (активной ссылкой)

Tags: php, wordpress

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые гуру.

Да, плагин Акисмет всем хорош, помечает спам сообщения на ура. Но этих спам сообщений копится огромное количество, в 95% которых присутствует HTML ссылка(и). И этот список надо просматривать, ведь в него могут попасть и обычные сообщения от реальных комментаторов.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, код, который можно было бы вставить в **functions.php**, который проверяет в отправляемом сообщении наличие html тега `href=` и в случае его наличия выводит сообщение (wp_die), наподобие: **HTML тег ссылки в комментариях запрещён. Вернитесь и отредактируйте сообщение.**

Активно гуглил, но решения не нашёл, хотя это пару строк кода максимум…

Answer (score 0):

```
$spamArray = ['href', 'img'. 'что еще считаете нужным'];
```

забираем post запрос с вашим textarea, полагаю, потом

```
foreach ($spamArray as $spamVal)
{
    if (strpos($_POST['нужное поле'], $spamVal) > 0 ) {
         echo 'Ваше сообщение';
        break; // или die()
    }
}
```

P.S. Надеюсь в целом смысл ясен, на полный ответ не претендую, а код лепить в комментарии извращение(